# Let's migrate content from Technical Communication here

Tags: discussion, status-completed, migration

The Technical Communication site is not going to graduate from private beta due to not meeting the participation threshold. However, there are some good people and some good content in the private beta site, most of which would be on topic for us. We have the opportunity to migrate most of that content here, and hopefully bring a lot of the users as well.

However, it won't happen automatically. Per the discussion in this meta post on Technical Communication (https://techcomm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67/closure-notice-unfortunately-techcomm-se-will-not-advance-from-private-beta) doing a migration like this is not standard practice on Stack Exchange and if we want it we have to ask for it and come up with a plan to handle it intelligently.

Why would we want to? For a long time we have been trying to get Writers out of its rut so we could move toward graduation and become a full fledged site. ([Getting Writers out of its Rut](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1378/getting-writers-out-of-its-rut)). A big part of the problem that we have been trying to address with recent changes, including the change of name from Writers to Writing is to broaden the range of topics we cover so that we can actually fulfill our mandate of handling the full spectrum of writing questions. A big part of that is looking more like a place to ask other kinds of writing questions. An influx of tech writing questions, along with the people who ask and answer them, could go a long way to making us look like a site where all kinds of writing questions will find good answers.

So what do you say? Do we want to migrate the questions and users from technical communication over here? And if so, what guidelines should we establish for migrating questions and what can we do to ensure the migration goes smoothly?

Comment: COMPLETED — I have migrated all questions from Technical Communications SE in "The List". Anything that doesn't seem to fit this site in it's current state can be closed... or edited to improve that content.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, I agree -- there is good content on that site that would also fit here, so we should help them move it here if they want.  Some questions don't fit here; they do have some questions that are about verbal technical communication rather than writing, and some others that might not match up with our scope.  But there's a lot that does fit, and there aren't so many questions that reviewing the list would be a chore.

As [Robert Cartaino said in a comment there](https://techcomm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67/closure-notice-unfortunately-techcomm-se-will-not-advance-from-private-beta#comment86_67), we should do this thoughtfully and consensually.  We probably wouldn't want to pull questions that are closed or that are downvoted, for example.  Some, as I said, would be off-topic here.  The community there is already starting to identify questions they propose moving here.  Let's let compiling a list of candidates happen there, and then we can take a quick look to make sure we agree on the list.  That way, we can show SE that both sites agree, but we don't split the discussion of which questions between the two sites.  Implementation note: we have one week to get this done.

We can't migrate users; that's completely up to the users in question.  However, all they have to do is come here and click the "join" button and they'll be automatically associated with whatever content of theirs was migrated.

**Update:** The Tech Comm community has compiled a 
[list of questions to migrate](https://techcomm.meta.stackexchange.com/a/81/87).  You'll need to visit the private beta [from Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101439/technical-communication) to see them.

Comment: I agree; I am all for bringing over thoughtful upvoted questions to broaden our scope. and then maybe we'll finally have a canon answer for "how do I write a polite reminder email?" ;)

Comment: Let me know how I can help :)

Comment: @topicref since you're active there, do you feel up to sifting through questions and identifying migration possibilities?  We want to find good questions with good answers that fit the scope here, and make any needed edits before Robert pulls the trigger.  There's a meta post there for collecting suggestions.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I'll have some time this weekend, but not before... which is cutting it a little close. I don't feel comfortable committing to sorting and editing in that short of a time span :/ Maybe if someone with time in the next few days gets things started by sorting candidates, I can help look at tags and make edits to tailor questions to Writing as best I can?

Comment: @topicref sounds good.  And if all you have time for is to look at a few questions, that's fine -- pick a small tag, maybe.

Comment: @MonicaCellio cool - I'll head over to the other Meta post and see what I can volunteer for :)